# Foreign Key: Single Field Referencing Multiple Fields (In Same Table)

Tags: mysql

I am relatively new to foreign key usage in MySQL and was hoping for some help regarding them.

My problem is I have a table with that contains a number of columns, two of which depend on keys from another table. The general scheme is like this, where 'a' and 'b' are columns showing their relationships:

```
Table 1 (a)
Table 2 (a,b)
Table 3 (a,b) <-- Table in question
```

I have a foreign key in Table 3 that will cascade updates and deletes that happen in Table 1. What I would like to do is to have updates and deletes set column b to NULL in Table 3 upon changes to Table 2 (a should remain untouched in this case). Is there a way to set such a relationship up using a foreign key? Would I be better off using a trigger (never used before)?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: To further clarify, Table 2 has a and b as its primary key and changes to Table 2 would cause b in Table 3 to reflect those changes.

An Example:

```
Table 1:
a
1
2
Table 2:
a  b
1  1
1  2
2  1
2  2
Table 3:
a  b
1  1
2  1
2  2
```

Deleting row 1 from Table 2 currently results in:

```
Table 1:
a
1
2
Table 2:
a  b
1  2
2  1
2  2
Table 3:
a  b
1  NULL
2  NULL
2  2
```

What I would like is:

```
Table 1:
a
1
2
Table 2:
a  b
1  2
2  1
2  2
Table 3:
a  b
1  NULL
2  1
2  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign keys may also be defined with [`SET NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) (instead of `ON CASCADE`), and you can mix these definitions. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Table3 (
    a INT,
    b INT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES Table1(a)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES Table2(b)
        ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. This is what I originally had, but the problem is that Table 3's b columns are all set to NULL but I need changes in Table 2 (which has a and b as its primary key) to reflect its changes in Table 3. In other words, when a row is deleted in Table 2, only the row that matches Table 2's primary key are affected.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and have updated my question to hopefully provide enough information to my problem. Sorry it was unclear the first time.

Comment: @Jason Okay, then I believe you will need a trigger. However this use case is strange, could you explain the meaning of your tables and their relationships? I suspect your structure could be optimised.

Comment: It would be my pleasure. Table 1 is essentially a list of all parent items with their ids (column a). Table 3 consists of children of the parents in Table 1. These are identifiable by the id in Table 1 (column a) and are also given their own id (which would be a new column not there, perhaps c). Table 2 has items that have a one to many relationship with those in Table 3 (column b), but these relationships exist for each parent from Table 1 (hence why column a and b is the primary key for Table 2). I'm sorry if my explanation is confusing, but I would appreciate your advice very much!

Comment: I see two options here. Option A: the Parent-Child relationship still exists between T1 and T3 even after the record in T2 is deleted. Do not update anything in T3 after this deletion. Option B: the Parent-Child relationship between T1 and T3 depends on the existence of a corresponding record in T2. Drop T3, the relationship is covered by T2 :)